# Are there any public program that can calculate baryon acoustic oscillations (BAO) acoustic peak from the data Lyman alpha spectra of BOSS?

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, bao

Are there any public program that can calculate baryon acoustic oscillations (BAO) acoustic peak from the data Lyman alpha spectra of Baryon Oscillation Spectroscopic Survey (BOSS)? I am confused in programming a program. I think there may be some public code, but I didn't find it.

Any one can help me?